# How to synchronize heights of two elements

Tags: html, css, height

How can I synchronize the height of an image with the height of a text area, depending on the screen size? I do not want to use the left border of the text area because I want a visual separation between the left bar and the text. I do not want the width of the bar to be adjusted simultaneously, because it is only a visual separator in the page; the bar should be just as long as the text on its right side.
NB: the bar is not restricted to an image; it can be anything as long as the result is a colored vertical bar with the correct height.

```css
    html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    body {
      background-color: #fff8dc;
      color: grey;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 1em;
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    .common {
      background-color: #fff8dc;
      float: left;
      width: 25%;
      height: 100vh;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0 40px 10px 40px;
    }
    .detail {
      background-color: #fff8dc;
      float: left;
      margin: 0 20px 0 0;
      overflow: auto;
      height: 100%
    }
    .text {
      margin: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="common">
  <p>blabla</p>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="detail">
    <img src="widgets/spacer.gif" alt="vertical bar" width="30px" height="400px" style="background-color: #E3B90A;">
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    <h1>BLABLA</h1>
    <p>blablabla</p>
    <p>blablabla</p>
    <p>blablabla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

HTML:

```
<div class="common">
  <p>blabla</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="detail">
    <img src="widgets/spacer.gif" alt="vertical bar">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>BLABLA</h1>
    <p>blablabla</p>
    <p>blablabla</p>
    <p>blablabla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    body {
      background-color: #fff8dc;
      color: grey;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 1em;
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    .container{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    .common {
      background-color: #fff8dc;
      float: left;
      width: 25%;
      height: 100vh;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0 40px 10px 40px;
    }
    .detail {
      background-color: #E3B90A;
      width: 30px;
      height: auto;
    }
    .detail img{
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    .text {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/s84yxh8L/